# passing parameter to modal window with data-target is not working

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have designed one page consisting of one modal window which is opening with  tag.
I want to pass some parameters to modal window which i will be using to populate table data based on the parameter value.It is working with one parameter but not working with another parameter.

Following is the HTML to open modal window......

```
<table id="MyTable1" class="table table-sm table-striped table-lightfont paginated">
                  <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","GRP_DESC"); ?></th>
                      <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MODULE_NAME"); ?></th>
                      <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","GMA_ACCESS_FLAG"); ?></th>
                      <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","OPTIONS"); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php
                    if ($_SESSION['$language']="E") {
                      $groupdata=SelectData("group_module_access,user_group,modules","gma_id,gma_grp_id,grp_desc,gma_module_id,module_name,gma_access_flag","gma_grp_id=grp_id and gma_module_id=module_id","gma_grp_id,gma_id");
                    }
                    else {
                      $groupdata=SelectData("group_module_access,user_group,modules","gma_id,gma_grp_id,grp_bldesc as grp_desc,gma_module_id,module_blname as module_name,gma_access_flag","gma_grp_id=grp_id and gma_module_id=module_id","gma_grp_id,gma_id");
                    }
                    foreach ($groupdata as $groupdatalist) {
                      //$allids[]=$groupdatalist["gma_id"]; ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $groupdatalist["grp_desc"];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $groupdatalist["module_name"];?></td>
                      <?php if($groupdatalist["gma_access_flag"]=="N"):?>
                        <td style="text-align:right;width:10px;"><input type="checkbox" name="accessflag[]" id="accessflag"
                          value="<?php echo "{$groupdatalist['gma_id']}"?>"/> </td>
                      <?php else:?>
                        <td style="text-align:right;width:10px;"><input type="checkbox" checked name="accessflag[]" id="accessflag" width="10px"
                          value="<?php echo "{$groupdatalist['gma_id']}"?>"/> </td>
                      <?php endif;?>
                      <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $groupdatalist["gma_grp_id"];?></td>
                      <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $groupdatalist["gma_module_id"];?></td>
                      <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="gmaid" id="gmaid" value="<?php echo $groupdatalist["gma_id"];?>"></td>

                      <!--<td style="display:none"><input type="text" name="allids[]" value="<//?php echo "{$groupdatalist['gma_id']}"?>"/></td>-->
                      <td>
                        <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_id'];?>">

                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-sm shadow-none"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MENUPERMISSION");?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                          </a>
                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Here is the modal window HTML.....

```
<div id="myModal-<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id'];?>" class="modal show fade" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h6 class="modal-title">Menu List</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="control-container" style="padding:10px;">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
                    <label style="color:red">
                      <?php //session_start();
                      if (!empty($_SESSION['$SaveMsg'])) { echo $_SESSION['$SaveMsg']; }
                      unset($_SESSION['$SaveMsg']);
                      ?>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","GRP_DESC"); ?>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="text-control" type="text" name="grpid" id="grpid"
                    value="" readonly required maxlength="50" style="width:100%;display:none;" autofocus />
                    <input class="text-control" type="text" name="grpname" id="grpname"
                    value="" readonly required maxlength="50" style="width:100%" autofocus />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MODULE_NAME"); ?>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="text-control" type="text" name="moduleid" id="moduleid"
                    value="" readonly required maxlength="50" style="width:100%;display:none" autofocus />
                    <input class="text-control" type="text" name="modulename" id="modulename"
                    value="" readonly required maxlength="50" style="width:100%" autofocus />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <?php $gmaid= "<script>document.writeln(gmaid);</script>";
                echo $gmaid;?>
<!--table starts here -->
<table id="MyTable2" class="table table-sm table-striped table-lightfont paginated">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MENUACCESS","MENUNAME"); ?></th>
      <!--<th><//?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MODULE_NAME"); ?></th>-->
      <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MENUACCESS","ACCESS_FLAG"); ?></th>
      <!--<th><//?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MENUACCESS","OPTIONS"); ?></th>-->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

</table>
<!-- table ends here -->


                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                    <?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"BUTTON","CANCEL"); ?>
                  </button>
                  <button type="submit" name="updmenuperm" formnovalidate class="btn btn-primary"> <!--onclick="DispMsg(<//?php echo "'".$_SESSION['AlertMsg']."'";?>)"-->
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                    <?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"BUTTON","SAVE"); ?>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Above code is working perfectly but if i am using another value as parameter it is not opening the modal window at all.
for ex. if i am using $groupdatalist['gma_id'] which is integer value, it is not opening modal window.

Comment: Hi, so when you try to use $groupdatalist['gma_id'] , you change it in both section right ?

Comment: yes and the data-target is in table <td> tag

Comment: <td>
                            <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id'];?>">
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-sm shadow-none"
                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"MODULEACCESS","MENUPERMISSION");?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                              </a>
                            </span>
                          </td>

Comment: So if the code works with one parameter and not the other one, it has to come from your params. Try to var_dump them to make sure what is returned

Comment: actually just now i noticed, when the value is same for all rows then it is working but when value is different for all rows then it is not working. like the value of $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id'] is same for all rows but the value of $groupdatalist['gma_id'] is different for all rows. I tried by using another parameter which has the same value for all rows and it is working

Comment: So are you saying that you have mutliple row with same ID ? An ID is unique, so if you have multiple element with a similar Id , it won't work

Comment: i mean to say if i am passing the parameter which has same value in all rows then it is opening modal window but if i am passing the parameter which has different values in all rows then it is not opening modal window. This link is given in table <td> tag and table is populated from database. $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id'] is array which is fetching the data in the table <td> tag. so i want to pass the value of the parameter of the clicked row so that i can populate another table based on the value of passed parameter in the modal window.

Comment: i can pass the parameter using javascript also but how can i use the value of this parameter to populate table in the modal window. following is the script for this...

Comment: <script>
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  //get data-id attribute of the clicked element
  var gmaid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('book_id').gmaid;
  
  //populate the textbox
  $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="gmaid"]').val(gmaid);
});
  </script>

Comment: anybody please help me.

Comment: Just try not to spam the conversation asking for help :)  Can you please edit your question with your complete code. This way it will be easier to figure it out

Comment: Hi i edited my question with complete code, actually i am not familiar about how to use stack overflow, that's why it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues here. 
First a `</div>` is missing at the end.

---

Then you are defining $groupdatalist in a foreach, but trying to use it outside the loop:

```
<div id="myModal-<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id'];?>" class="modal show fade" data-backdrop="static">
```

If you want one modal per `<td>` you have to move your modal into the foreach loop.

---

Finally, you call the modal using $groupdatalist['**gma_id**']

```
 <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_id'];?>">
```

but the modal ID is define using a different variable : $groupdatalist['**gma_grp_id**']:

```
<div id="myModal-<?php echo $groupdatalist['gma_grp_id'];?>"
```

Comment: hi Thanks a lot for your help, after making changes as u advised, it is working fine but as soon as i am trying to create <table> inside the modal-body window. its getting messy.my existing table inside the main form is disturbing. please advise.

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to select the answer if you think that resolved your issue :) . About your question, I'm not sure to understand what you mean.. Sorry can you explain  ?

Comment: I have one table which has many rows and from this table <a> anchor tag i am opening modal window. it is showing my table in the main page fine till i add another table in the modal window. as soon as i am adding another table inside the modal window. my table in the main page is getting messy and only one row is shown there and remaining rows are going out of the table.if i could attach screen shot then i would have done that.

Comment: If I understand you want to add another table after #MyTable2 ?

Comment: no i want to add #MyTable2 itself inside myModal based on the parameters passed to modal window.